# How do I get a numeric input in a Leaflet map using Shiny to work?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, r-leaflet

Here is some reproducible R/Shiny code that I whipped up to illustrate the issue I am having... Basically, if I try to embed a numeric input into a leaflet map, as illustrated below, I am unable to call the value input specified in the numeric input.

After scouring the web, I have a hunch that a JS-based solution is required because of the way shiny and leaflet render maps. I tried creating a UI output, then a render a UI numeric input, attempted various strategies using reactive functions but did not get very far. Any help would be appreciated as I have been banging my head on the wall trying to figure this out.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

content <- paste(sep = "<br/>",
             "<b>Change number below:</b>",
             numericInput("numeroUno", label = NULL, value = 1)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  "This is a map",
  leafletOutput("myMap"),  
  numericInput('numeroDos', label = NULL, value = 5),
  textOutput("mapPopupLink"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$myMap <- renderLeaflet({
 leaflet() %>% 
    setView(lng = 25.0343, lat = 77.3963, zoom = 5) %>% 
    addPopups(-122.327298, 47.597131, content, options = popupOptions(closeButton = FALSE)) %>%
    addTiles() %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenTopoMap)
  })

 output$mapPopupLink <- renderText({
      paste("The ui-based widget prints: ", input$numeroDos, ". But the server-based widget does not: ", input$numeroUno)
   })
 }
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please help!

Let me know if you need additional info.

Comment: The function that creates `content` doesn't make sense. If you're using `numericInput` it needs to be within the UI code.

Comment: Do you know how to make the numeric input work in a leaflet popup? My example renders a widget on the UI if you run the code but does not have any functionality... Even if I were to create a UI object and pass it through the server side it would not work.

Comment: I would suggest looking at this [example](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny-examples/tree/master/063-superzip-example) as a starting point. For one, you need to have the inputs located within something like `tabPanel()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Phil. Your example illustrates a different concept compared to implementing a workable numeric input/widget inside a popup.

Comment: Yes, but you'll note that the structure of the UI and server code should actually resemble that example.